# TypeScript "Cannot find module" when using WebPack inline loader syntax, solve without using @ts-ignore?

Tags: typescript, webpack

I perfectly know why the error is raised but I can't find a way to suppress it (that is not `// @ts-ignore`). I'm using `style-loader` with the [inline syntax](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#inline):

```
import styles from '!style-loader?injectType=lazyStyleTag!css-loader!vendor/style.css';
```

> Cannot find module '!style-loader?injectType=lazyStyleTag!css-loader!vendor/style.css'' or its corresponding type declarations.

How should I "instruct" TypeScript that the import is legit?

**EDIT**: declaration as per answer:

```
declare module '!style-loader?*' {
  const value: { use: (options?: Record<string, any>) => void, unuse: () => void };
  export default value;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript allows you to declare a custom module import on your own, specifically you might use a [wildcard module declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#wildcard-module-declarations) so following things:

- Declare your custom typings files such as `./typings/index.d.ts`

```
declare module '!style-loader?*' {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

- Include this `typings` dir into your `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  // ...
  "include": ["...", "typings"]
}
```

One more thing, you need to check which version of Typescript supports this wildcard module declaration.

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot, i've updated the answer to a better declaration.